# How to divide two blocks equally

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have two rows. For the first one, I want it to take col11 and for the second one I want it exactly the same as the first but divided into two. The first one is smaller then the other one. For example, take col4 and for the other take col5. The result should look like this image :[image]

This is the code that didn't get the desired result:

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-xl-11 col-lg-11 col-md-11  overflow-auto">
    overview <br />
    overview <br />overview <br />overview <br />overview <br />overview
    <br />overview
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row d-flex justify-content-between">
  <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12  overflow-auto">tes</div>

  <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-12  overflow-auto">
    <br />overview <br />overview <br />overview <br />overview
    <br />overview <br />overview <br />overview <br />overview
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example bellow, I made 2 rows, one row has 100% and 1 columns. The second row has 2 columns, one of which has 50% and the other, another `.row` which contains 2 more columns, in which each represents 25%

resulting in:

[image]

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm bg-success">
        100%
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm bg-primary">
        50%
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm bg-primary">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm bg-secondary">
            25%
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm bg-primary">
            25%
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

if you want to give each column a diferent width, you could add each one a span, in bootstrap you can use: `.col-5`, for example instead of `.col-sm`